# How to create href links that links to a cell within a ninja table [short code] within an https WP knowledge base article

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, anchor, shortcode

I am working within a Wordpress site that uses Ninja tables. This table has anchor tags in the cells located in the first column.   Ninja tables are assigned shortcode and can exist on multiple pages. However I think that my href link would need to be specific to the page on which the Ninja table sits, include the short code for the ninja table and then include the anchor tag within the cell.

For example, I would access an https page; then access a ninja table -- here's the sample short code

```
[ninja_tables id="12345"]
```

and then I want to link an anchor tag for the word `#phone`.

I can't add a real URL as my question is work related.

How can I stack all that and make it work?

Many thanks!

Something like this?